# Installing a certificate on a PC

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an internal website in our company that uses HTTPS and the Server's certificate. The thing is since this certificate is self-signed, when anyone browse to that web site it gives a certificate warning. What I did on my PC I opened the site in IE and then clicked on the certificate error in the address bar and on the general tab clicked on Install certificate, selected Local Machine as the store location and placed it on the Trusted root certification authorities. Using a MMC I also verified that this certificate is installed successfully. But the issue is that the certificate warning is still there!

Comment: is your network managed? For example, is there Active Directory?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem as you before, and i think it is impossible to remove properly the warning even if you use firefox, chrome or you own web browser based on Internet Explorer libs, your company must bye a certificate from companies like verisign. The only way i found to remove the warning message using IE is to trap the window wich warn you using WINAPI (getting window handle by the window title of the warning popup then find the handle of "OK" button and send a message to simulate a press on it)..

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this to trusted sites in IE. If you have group policy access it can be set for users also.

Open IE

```
Click Tools and select Internet Options
Click the Security Tab
Select Trusted Sites icon and set the Security level to Medium Low.
Add the site to Trusted Sites by clicking sites button. 
Close all the Windows. Then open the browser.
```

See if that will work for you.